# What's the software used in Megaman X speedruns?

Tags: emulation, snes, speedrun, mega-man-x, mega-man

I'm starting out with my personal journey toward a 100% speedrun of Megaman X and I noticed that pretty much every speedrunner on YouTube are using a software that keeps track of time for each level: do you know what it is?[image]

Comment: can you tell if he's manually triggering the time splits or if they happen automatically?

Comment: No, I can't tell: it could be, since they are usually able to read the live chat and talk.

Comment: [This page](https://www.speedrun.com/support/learn/resources-for-speedrunners) probably gives you a good idea of what they might be using, or at least similar programs

Comment: @TimmyJim thank you so much for these useful resources!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're probably using a program called [Live Split](https://livesplit.org/). It's discussed on the speedrun.com forums here:

https://www.speedrun.com/mmx/forums/2ilke

Comment: The software people used to use was XSplit, but this might be a decade out of date.

Comment: @qwr XSplit is a livestreaming software, not a speedrun splits software. (and for that matter these days everyone uses OBS instead)